# How to get the header info of the first news on the page using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to navigate to each of the links and get their first news on the page.but can't get a unique xpath for the header info across all pages

Refer the attached pic, it shows 2 elements. how can i make it as unique to fetch only the header / title news.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many headers on that page and they are changing. I mean some news are coming and being removed from this page.
If you want to get all the news title texts you can get all the headers elements and then iterate over them and extract their texts.
Something like this:

```java
List<WebElement> headers = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-pica-bold nw-o-link-split__text']"));
for (WebElement header : headers){    
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", header);
    System.out.println(header.getText());
}
```

Comment: Sure, but the thing is I can't find an xpath that can be common across all links from home page. the one you have mentioned is also not getting the header of all sublinks - sucha s  NEWS has one kind of header and SPORTS has a diferent xpath for header, REEL & WORKLLIFE are even different Xpath for header info. THis is the challenge I am facing.

Comment: As mentioned by DebanjanB we answered your question clearly. What you asking now is another question. We can try helping you with it, but you should accept some answer here, maybe at least upvote others, who were helpful, and ask another, new question for your new requirements. Please describe your self as clear as possible there to make us clearly understand what exactly you looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the header of the first news you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *Java* and *xpath* and *`getText()`*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'gs-u-display-inline-block@m')]//h3[@class='gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-paragon-bold nw-o-link-split__text']"))).getText());
  ```
- *Python* and *css_selector* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='gs-u-display-inline-block@m'] h3.gs-c-promo-heading__title.gel-paragon-bold.nw-o-link-split__text"))).text)
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Russia orders oldest rights group Memorial to shut
  ```
- **Note** : For *Python* clients you have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: @JeyanthiRanjit Isn't your question _`it shows 2 elements. how can i make it as unique to fetch only the header / title news`_?

Comment: The layouts of none of the mentioned sites are identical, why do you feel a single shot [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120) will work across all of those sites?

Comment: That is a coding challenge I have been given with in an interview. If its not possible, will they give it as a question? But please advise if there is any strategy to achieve the result.

Comment: @JeyanthiRanjit If you want a canonical answer based on multiple bbc.com sites, you may like to ask a new question. As per the description of this question _`it shows 2 elements. how can i make it as unique to fetch only the header / title news`_ I think you got well researched answers.

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB

Answer (score 1):

You can select only the first element by using the parent's first child  and then point to the child element, for example:

`//div/div[1]/div/a/h3[@class="gs-c-promo-heading__title gel-paragon-bold nw-o-link-split__text"]`

`[1]` is equal to `:first-child`

Comment: Thanks, the challenge I am facing is while automating this process of navigating through each link from home page, I can only mention a common xpath to get header info across all pages. But its changing for every page. Can you help in sorting a common Xpath which can be used in an automation script to get the header across All link pages from Home page, when clicked one by one ?